# What is the use of `_notes` in module?

Tags: extensions, magento-1

This is first time I have seen in one extension, `_notes` folder. I am trying to understand what's the logic having this file.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/typechange-products.html

This extension has 2 files, that I don't understand

1. `Module/controllers/Adminhtml/Catalog/_notes/filename.xml`
2. `Module/Model/_notes/filename.xml`

In that file it has following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<node>
     <file name="Observer.php" server="[example.vizz.extension]/public_html/" local="[some_numbers]" remote="[some_numbers]" />
</node>
```

In `Module/controllers/Adminhtml/Catalog/_notes/filename.xml` there is only file name different.

Any idea on this?

**I know this is third party extension and most likely this question will get closed. But I am more of asking about the code/file that exist in this module.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dwsync.xml` is a file created by `Dreamweaver`. `Dreamweaver` uses it to synchronize files in a Dreamweaver project.

> The `dwsync.xml` files are located in the `_notes` folders, which are
>   hidden by default in Dreamweaver. So check for the `_note`s folders
>   and `dwsync.xml` files in the Windows Explorer or Mac file browsers.
>   The `dwsync.xml` files only reside locally. Dreamweaver never uploads
>   the `dwsync.xml` files to the server, and there is no reason to upload
>   them to the server.

You can find more info from this [link](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/troubleshoot-synchronization-problems-dreamweaver-cs4.html)

So I think form this we can easily say that they have developed or open extension files on Dreamweaver. You can easily remove this directory it's not usable by `Magento`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will see if removing those files have any effect.

Comment: I have checked this and it's working fine in my system. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `_notes` folders do not belong there. The person who created the module most likely built it on Windows. Those folders are generated by Windows and they are safe to delete.